# How to use an environment variable in Sapper's template.html?

Tags: environment-variables, sapper

I would like to use an environment variable within `template.html` so that I can change the content in the head for all pages based on where I'm running the app. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I never found a way to put environment variables in `template.html`, but I passed what I needed through `server.js`, picked it up in `_layout.svelte`, and included it in a `<svelte:head>` element.